# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _lib_engine:couldn‘t find specific module

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

> error when "import nfstream" in python3.9.15(anaconda virtual env in windows11, env variants have been add to the PATH)

> logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\nfstream\lib\site-packages\nfstream\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .streamer import NFStreamer
  File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\nfstream\lib\site-packages\nfstream\streamer.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .meter import meter_workflow
  File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\nfstream\lib\site-packages\nfstream\meter.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .engine import create_engine, setup_capture, setup_dissector, activate_capture
  File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\nfstream\lib\site-packages\nfstream\engine\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .engine import create_engine, setup_capture, setup_dissector, activate_capture
  File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\nfstream\lib\site-packages\nfstream\engine\engine.py", line 16, in <module>
    from _lib_engine import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _lib_engine: couldn’t find specific module
```

> 1.I have tried `pip uninstall nfstream`, and then `pip install -U nfstream`

> 2.And I have dowload 'msvcp71.dll', 'msvcr71.dll' to windows/system32 and windows/SysWOW64

> 3.also I have dowload all off c++ runtime tools and development kits

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsLWt.png)

But the error exists as well!!! Help me please, thank you very much.

Comment: Not a Conda/Anaconda issue. The `nfstream` devs only push wheels to PyPI, which should be static builds (no external links). Please add version information for `nfstream` to the question. Also, [this appears to be an open Issue](https://github.com/nfstream/nfstream/issues/145) and you should report detailed information there. Also, maybe try some other Python versions - both of you having this error are attempting Python 3.9.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you did, i.e. provided a [mcve]. As a new user, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by running `nfstream` in an Ubuntu environment instead of on windows.